# jQuery UI autocomplete trigger blur

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete, blur

I've got a text field with jQuery UI autocomplete. I want the user to type something, have the autocomplete to show options and then when the user clicks an option I want it to trigger blur/focusout, to indicate that the user has selected a value.

Unfortunately, it seems that jQuery UI keeps the focus on the text field when the auto complete option has been clicked.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`close`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#event-close) event of the autocomplete field.

Quick reference:

> Triggered when the menu is hidden. Not every close event will be
>   accompanied by a change event.

Code:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    close: function(){
        this.blur();
    }
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/T2WRc/

Answer (score 0):

Irvin's answer helped me figure out how to fix this, but using the close function can have a bad side effect.  If the autofill stops showing results after starting to show results, the close function is triggered, so in this case the blur would be triggered too, before anything is selected.

Instead, just add the "this.blur();" to the select function after you chose what you are returning (or just add it in if you are using the default select).

Using his code example:

```
$("#tags").autocomplete({
    source: availableTags,
    select: function(){
        this.blur();
    }
});
```